# Email preview via api

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I have a .net app which allows users to select an email and send to a list of subscribers. I'd like to provide the user with a preview or thumbnail of the email they select before they send it.

Is this possible to do using the soap api or fuel sdk? I've seen a couple of questions related to thumbnails but none have been answered. The previewURL property would be nice to use but it seems to only be part of the Send object and not the Email object for some reason.

Comment: Please refer working: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159520/get-preview-of-email-with-ampscript-using-rest-api?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a route that will return HTML for an email -

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/{your email id}}/preview?kind=html,text
```

This should return a payload for you including the rendering in HTML of the message for preview.

Let me know if you get that working.

Comment: Is this approach the same as retrieving the htmlbody property of the Email object?
I've got it working but for the text emails it doesn't show anything.
I just want to retrieve a preview of what will be sent by passing in an email id. Is that not possible?

Also, could you please point me to the documentation for the api url you posted above?

Comment: No - this will render the content with all substitution strings replaced with dummy content.  There currently isn't any live documentation for this route. I've updated to allow for text email.

Comment: Great. There doesn't seem to be any dummy content but I can live with that. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I am able to preview with this URL: https://members.s7.exacttarget.com/Content/Email/EmailThumbnail.aspx?eid=1007&w=300&h=500&showHF=true But if I try this: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/1007/preview?kind=html&access_token=35cw7tw22xh49pa98fv3uhcg nothing. Thoughts?