# Get Preview of Email with AMPscript Using Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email

I'm trying to get the SendPreview rendering of an E-Mail with Contact Data from a Dataextension. The E-Mail includes AMPScript.

I tryed the following route:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/{emailID}/dataExtension/id:{dataExtensionGuid}/contacts/{rowNo.}/preview?kind=html
```

Here is an example:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/103985/dataExtension/id:a2694402-4932-e611-a584-00110a6822ad/contacts/0/preview?kind=html
```

But it doesn't work. I always get

```json
    {
        "message": "Internal Server Error",
        "errorcode": 0,
        "documentation": "https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/500"
    }
```

I found this solution in this thread but it seems not documented anywhere.
[How does the ExactTarget Email preview REST API work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/how-does-the-exacttarget-email-preview-rest-api-work)

Is it possible to get a SendPreview rendering over API?
And if yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following request works for me:

```json
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /guide/v1/emails/[emailID here]/dataExtension/key:[DE External Key goes here]/contacts/key:[Subscriber Key that you want to preview here]/preview?kind=html
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This returns the response payload:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "/v1/emails/4144/dataExtension/0fa2a58b-39c5-e511-9164-00110a68d751/row/148/preview"
      }
    },
    "views": [
      {
        "contentType": "vnd.exacttarget.message.email.htmlBody",
        "content": "<html><head>\r\n</head><body>\r\n<h2>Hello Katie</h2>\r\n</body></html>"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Does this work with content builder as well as classic builder emails?

Comment: Great question. I've tried but I get the error `Email::BuildMessage(string, int)- This method can only be called with a valid Email ID.` I can't see an easy way to get `EmailID`. I used my browser inspector to view the response payload when opening content builder and I'm using the ID value which I assume is correct. buy that's not working for me.

Comment: The only way I have found to 'easily' pull EmailID from content builder is with the EmailID string (%%_emailid%%) placed inside the email and then do a preivew.  I have the feeling it may not work as the classic and content builder emails are stored in 2 completely different areas.  I definitely HOPE this works though as I have been looking for this very thing for a while now.

Comment: This did not work for me with Classic Content...

Comment: Dean, I use this regularly with both Classic Content and Content Builder emails. If you are still having issues, reach out to me at eliot.com.au and I'll walk you through this.

Comment: I keep getting a 401 "Not Authorized" response using the route provided using an access token created from the /v2/token endpoint using only the client id and client secret from an installed package. Does the access token have to be from an actual user? The installed app has every permission.

I'm new to Marketing Cloud so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @LukeFreeland, I use this all the time. You're right, I'm sure it's obvious. Happy to jump on a quick call and look at this together. I've reached out to you separately. I'll share the answer here, once we have it!

Comment: There were multiple issues with mine but @EliotHarper was able to help me out and fix them. Make sure that the email content is Approved and available. Make sure that you do a "POST" and not a "GET" to the preview endpoint. Doing a "GET" was returning a 404 "Not Found".

Comment: Still is not possible to do this using Content Builder?

Comment: @marioruiz this route still works. For Content Builder emails, remember to get the email id using the method in an earlier comment.

Comment: @EliotHarper thanks for figuring this out. I can confirm it works, although it's odd because I can pull the email id via the REST API, but the id I get from that call doesn't work, whereas the id I get from using %%_emailid%% does work.

Comment: There's a field called EmailID in the data view _Job. Is this the same we are talking about here? If so, then we can as well query this data view with some parameters and found the needed EmailID.

Comment: Is this possible any longer?  No endpoint I can find in documentation matches /guide/*

Comment: Yes it still works, but it's undocumented.

Comment: Yes @wondergoat77 I just got it working, but using objectid, legacy email id and this for the row number _CustomObjectKey

Answer (score 13):

This is an internal only route, that currently is NOT supported.  It should not be used in production environments.  The route has no ownership internally, and could stop working without notice.