# How can I fetch code for a Cloud Page from a file on Dropbox?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I've realized that Landing Page Publish is slow. So, While I was looking for solving this issue, I found that can be improve Cloud Page in Dropbox using %%=TreatAsContent(HTTPGet('')=%% Method.

But, For some reason, that does not seem to work as expected.

TreatAsContent Method shows the HTML Language Source, Not the page to which the code is applied in Dropbox.

Could you tell me what I missed and How can I solve this problem?

Firstly, I Created Landing Page Using AMPScript.
[image]

and, Click the Specific link In Email, Move to the HTML Source Page in Dropbox.
[image]

Comment: Did you follow these instructions step by step? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161622/developing-a-marketing-cloud-email-locally-with-ampscript-is-a-pain

Comment: @zuzannamj
Thank you for the reply. It's working Properly. You are so smarter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append `?dl=0&raw=1` to the end of the dropbox url and insert between your TreatAsContent and HTTPGet functions as such:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(HTTPGet('https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghijk123/my_page.html?dl=0&raw=1'))=%%
```

Comment: Thanks you for the Answer Josh! It also works Properly. I really Thanks.

Comment: It's worthwhile noting that this should only be used for testing, and I would strongly suggest swapping out for your actual code once testing is completed.